# Convert all tables in the active worksheet to ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet

I'm making a tool that will cleanup excel documents so that they're in a database-friendly format (for scheduled import into a database).

As part of this tool, I want to convert all tables in the active worksheet to ranges (using VBA). The script below is almost what I want - it converts all tables to ranges for **all worksheets** in the workbook:

```
Sub ConvertTablesToRange()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, objList As ListObject
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each objList In wks.ListObjects
            objList.Unlist
        Next objList
    Next wks
End Sub
```

Instead of doing this for all worksheets, I just want to do it for the **active worksheet**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub ConvertTablesToRange()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, objList As ListObject
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For Each objList In wks.ListObjects
        objList.Unlist
    Next objList
End Sub
```